# What is the <b: syntax used in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I am trying to do a small customization to change the Open Graph image in a blog on blogspot.com.

When I looked at the template Html source, it contains massive (>4,000 lines of) code using `<b:xxx ...>`.  What is this `b` tag language used? Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: Check &read OverAPI guides: http://overapi.com/blogger

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Blogger widget tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995) to add specific data and page elements in your template.